# Crashlytics do Firebase: como debuggar erros não fatais?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, debug, log

Olá! Boa tarde.
Tenho uma aplicação para Android (desenvolvida no Android Studio) que usa a lib [MPAndroid Chart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) (uma lib para charts).

Como qualquer gráfico que desejamos montar, primeiro precisamos ter os dados que irão compor esse gráfico. Quando estamos utilizando essa lib (MPAndroid Chart) e tentamos construir um gráfico sem dados (sem entradas), por padrão, ela exibe no lugar do gráfico, uma mensagem de "erro" que diz que não há dados para que possa exibir algum gráfico. Esta mensagem é assim:

[image: Gráfico sem dados]

A questão é que esse problema só está ocorrendo em alguns casos e como **não é um problema fatal** (não causa "crash" na aplicação), eu preciso, de alguma forma, coletar informações da minha aplicação nos aparelhos dos usuários que estão relatando esse bug a fim de entender o porque desse problema.

Para isso, pensei em utilizar o Crashlytics.

Segui o passo a passo da documentação oficial do Firebase para conseguir gerar relatórios personalizados e captar informações que possam me ajudar a debugar esse problema. Adicionei diversas linhas de código como esta:

```
Crashlytics.setString("Posts no face pagina 2", user_Likes_ARRAY_page2.toString());
```

**A questão é:**

Não estou conseguindo visualizar e nem sequer encontrar no console do Firebase, o local aonde eu deveria conseguir ver esses logs personalizados.

Também não consigo dizer se esse é o melhor jeito de tratar erros não fatais na aplicação mas que só ocorre em alguns casos.

Alguém poderia me ajudar, por gentileza?